# Delphi unable to serialize WCF service collections (lists/arrays of integers, strings, objects, etc.) correctly

Tags: wcf, delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-2010

Attempting to pass a collection (array of integers, strings, List of objects, doesn't matter) via WCF (developed in Visual Studio 2012), the items inside the collection are not not present.  No errors, the collection property on the complex object itself isn't null, and only the collection's content is missing.

The service interface contains a number of methods with data contracts from various satellite assemblies:

```
[OperationContract]
EmailPreferencesUpdateResponse UpdateEmailPreferences(EmailPreferencesUpdateRequest request);

public class EmailPreferencesUpdateRequest
{
    public int EmailId { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public int EmailFormat { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public int[] EmailPreferences { get; set; }
}
```

Using Fiddler, the Delphi generated SOAP request is slightly different than the message generated by the WCF test client:

[image: Fiddler]

I've tested this behavior in Delphi 2010, XE2, and easily reproducible in any WCF service with a method where a complex data-transfer-object parameter contains a collection (array, List, IEnumerable, doesn't matter).

Is there a '*trick*' to getting the Delphi SOAP namespace correct?  Is there an Delphi WSDL import option (using the WSDL import UI) missing (or I need to un-check):
[image: WSDL Import Options]

Is there something I can do to the WCF service itself that wouldn't break existing contracts?

I've already made sure the endpoint is basicHttpBinding, tried using the XmlSerializerFormat (image below, which it sorta' works for Delphi, ran into other issues), but breaks already existing contracts used throughout existing .Net clients/implementations.

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "Delphi", Namespace = "SomeRandomNamespace")]
[XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document, Use = OperationFormatUse.Literal)]
public interface IDelphiCompatibleOrderTakingService
```

Comment: Please do not paste screenshots of code. Paste code.

Comment: I gave up hooking Delphi direct into WCF. I always endup making an intermediate DLL in .NET that exposes the needed functionality via COM.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thank you for the reply.  The code itself isn't/wasn't as important as the behavior in question.  I didn't want to get into a lengthy back'n'forth about specific syntax and fan flames of how to 'properly' name namespaces.

Comment: Fine. Please replace the screenshots with actual code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : Screenshots replaced with actual code.

Comment: @whosrdaddy : Thank you for the reply.  I started going that route, but there are over a hundred classes scattered across several assemblies I'd have to 'mirror' classes/properties/behavior to add [ComVisible(true)]. I don't mind doing it, but 'the powers that be' feel this is a Delphi issue.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to resolve the issue by selecting '*Map pure collections to wrapper class types*'

[image: WSDL Import Options Dialog]

Comment: Sometime array of types have problem for setting Fxxx__Specified property. You can change manually SetxxxArray function for setting Fxxx__Specified as true.